# Implementing a service to communicate against a BLE device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am working on an android project that requires communication against a BLE device.

as for now I am quite done - however I have one thing I cant solve - 

 I want to use a service to coomunicate against the BLE device and communicate

with thata service only by sending and recieving broadcasts.

my question is - for some reason when I try to connect to the device inside the service 

by making the service extend LeScancallbak finding the device and connecting to it takes much longer and also the BLE GATT server is null (since the gattcallback is never called) 
however if I bind the service to activity and implement that LeScancallbak in the activity its a metter of acouple of milliseconds - 

 Did anyone also had the same problem or possibly have an answer to that strange behavior?

I want to use only the service to communicate against the bluetooth device since I want to stay connected to the device even when the application UI is not running (i.e. leave a background service) plus it looks more logical that connecting every activity to that service upon changing screens.

 In case anyone have a better way to achieve that, I wil be happy to hear about it.

Comment: Hi @Taranfx I can upload my code, but you can take a look at steven rudenko code on github I used his code as something to start from trying to implement his BleService the same way (disconnected from the UI) will lead to the same result take a look at here - 
https://github.com/StevenRudenko/BleSensorTag/blob/master/src/sample/ble/sensortag/BleService.java

Answer (score 1):

BLE has a lot of issues on Android, and implementing a service like you want will be difficult. I would recommend integrating the BLEService library produced by Ratio. The source is available on GitHub: https://github.com/RatioLabs/BLEService

Comment: Hi @Jschools tnx for your answer but I already did something similar - The point of my question is not about implementation since I am basically done, what i am looking is for a way to improve my code since as for now it does not provide the full functionalities that I need and that is due to the fact that for some reason I cannot connect to a BLE device through a service and have to bind the connection part to an activity.
The project you supplied as an example is a great wrapper for all the nasy stuff, but like I said I am alredy done with that